# Why can't I initialize a vector of pointers using fill constructor?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, stdvector

I'm trying to create a vector of pointers pointing to objects of a specific class.
This is my code and I expected each pointer to point to different objects. But turns out they have the same address values. Why?

```
class A{
    public:
    int a;
    A(): a(0){}
    A(int a): a(a){}
};
int main() {
    vector<A*> v(2, new A());
    cout<<v[0]<<endl;   // will print 0x602000000010
    cout<<v[1]<<endl;   // will print 0x602000000010 (same)
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The wrong expectation. The same pointer is copied to all vector elements. That is very well described in the manual: *Constructs the container with count copies of elements with value `value`.*

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Can you send me a link of a reliable manual? There're multiple and I'm not sure which one to refer to.

Comment: My goto is cppreference. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector, then scroll to constructor.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector. Then look at point 3) Constructs the container with count copies of elements with value value.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, the constructor for `std::vector` that you use will fill the vector with `count` (the 1<sup>st</sup> argument) *copies* of the *value* of the 2<sup>nd</sup> argument. In your case, those will each be copies of the address of the *single* `A` object created by the call to `new`.

To fill a vector with the addresses of *multiple* objects, you can use the [`std::generate` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate), passing a lambda, which creates a new object and returns its address, as the 'generator function' (3<sup>rd</sup> argument):

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> // For std::generate

class A {
public:
    int a;
    A() : a(0) {}
    A(int a) : a(a) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A*> v(2);
    std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [] { return new A; });
    std::cout << v[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << v[1] << std::endl;
    for (auto p : v) delete p; // The vector's destructor WON'T delete pointers

    // Or, to use the other constructor for A...
    std::vector<A*> vx(4);
    int i = 0;
    std::generate(vx.begin(), vx.end(), [&i] { return new A(i++); });
    for (auto e : vx) std::cout << e->a << std::endl; // 0, 1, 2, 3...
    for (auto p : vx) delete p;

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the destructor for a `std::vector` will properly delete **object** elements (calling the destructor for each) but it **won't** delete objects pointed-to by its elements; you have to do that yourself.